# reuse the ResultSet object in java

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

I am working on a swing project. In which i am using jdbc odbc Connection bridge to access the data from SQL database. I am using the following code

```
 try
  {
     Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcodbcDriver");
     Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:dsn");
     Statement st=con.createStatement();
     ResultSet rs=st.executeQuery("select * from temp");
     int count c=0;
     while(rs.next())
     {
      c++;
     }

   }
  catch(Exception ex)        
   {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

In the above code after while loop, if i use again the result set object then it throws the exception as result set is closed . Is there any other object instead of result set  to fetch the data from database in disconnected mode.

Comment: Do you mean you want to collect what is in the result set into another structure?

Comment: Why you want to use the result set after the while loop?Within the while loop itself, you can collect all the data.

Comment: I want to get again from result with the help of metaData

Comment: "to fetch the data from database in disconnected mode" Yes, that would be a challenge.

Comment: Renjith i have collected the data but again i want to use the same result set object is it possible.

Comment: @user1960524 well, it is not possible, see the answers

Comment: You cant...You have to collect the results to some list and process the data.Also from oracle docs :'A ResultSet object is automatically closed when the Statement object that generated 
it is closed, re-executed, or used to retrieve the next result from a sequence of 
multiple results.'

Comment: It does not make much sense to reuse the result set as (dependent on how caching is configured) it will probably just re-read data from the database again that is slow operation. It may be more reasonable to rembember the result.

Comment: @user1960524 yes for sure.Try to put that code in some other class and keep a function which will do your result set operations.And then call that function in the while loop from the present class.Make sure EDT dosn't freez.Try and let me know.I have implemented similar kind of thing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The result set doesn't **contain** the results, it's a kind of iterator over the results that still are in the database (or in a cache in the driver).

So that's totally normal.

If you want to keep a list of the results after you disconnected, just copy them to a concrete list before, for example an ArrayList. This means you'll have to do the interpretation of the columns (i.e. using `getInt` or `getString` or `getBinaryStream` and fetching the content, etc.) at the time of this copy.

Comment: Is it possible to store a result set to another result set for further use

Comment: You mean without disconnecting ?

Comment: yes i want to store result set in another before disconnecting first

Comment: If you disconnect, no result set can be usable. Copy the data into an arrayList or don't disconnect.

Answer (score 4):

> Is there any other object instead of result set to fetch the data from database in disconnected mode.

`ResultSet` gets the data after the connections has been established. And there is no other object to perform this task.

You should store the data in some list ( or other data structure) and within `while` loop fill that list from `ResultSet`

Comment: Is it possible to store the resultset in another resultset for further use

Comment: @user1960524 Yes, with a CachedRowSet (or one of the other RowSet implementations)